# How to require a controller (angularjs) in express (routes.js)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

I am trying to make a restful service and I want to put my callbacks in controllers so my routes.js file does not get congested with callbacks. I was using

```
controller = require(path.to.controller);
```

at the top of my routes.js and then I was able to use controller.myFunction(). But for some reason I am getting:

ReferenceError: angular is not defined

since my controller is just a regular angular controller with no export. Is there some way to export the controller or require a controller in express? I tried searching but couldn't find the same problem.

Comment: I don't have experience with express, but, is your angluar.js included?

Comment: yes my angular is included. it's the angular reference from angular.module in the controller file

Answer (score 0):

use require.config({}) function  since your controller is a js file give the path to the controller in the path section and in the shim section just export the same with one keyword and also put the deps as angular so that angular is loaded first and then you js file
the use require(keyword used for the controller)

Thanks